# Android Proguard - is it best practice to -keep all 3rd party libs?

Tags: android, proguard

I'm configuring Proguard for an app that uses 3rd party libraries. Is it "best practice" (in order to avoid future hard-to-find bugs) to include the line:

```
-keep class 3rd_party_lib_name.** {*;}
```

for every single 3rd party open source library that doesn't have specific Proguard instructions from its developer?

Also, a related question: is there a general guideline for which cases I should use

```
-keep class
```

and in which cases i should use

```
-keep public class
```

many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major problem with proguard and code obfuscation in general is that classname, methods and fields name are modified. ( i.e. `myExplicitMethodName()` became `a()` )

When a classname, method name or a field is modified, you cannot access it using the reflection API (i.e. `Class.classForName(...)` , ... )

Knowing that, it's a best practice to `-keep` all classes and libraries that can be invoked using the reflection API.

For 3rd party libraries, if you don't know if they use or not the reflection API : then `-keep`

For your own code: hopefully, you know in which classes you use it. So use `-keep` for those classes.

Note that some popular framework like dagger or jackson use the reflection API on your own classes, so if you use them, be careful!

Answer (score 3):

The fewer -keep options you can use, the better your results will be, in terms of optimization and obfuscation. If you don't have the time to find an optimal configuration, you can take a more conservative approach. The most conservative solution is to preserve all classes, fields, and methods in the library, so any internal reflection will continue to work:

```
-keep class 3rd_party_lib_name.** {*;}
```

Slightly less conservative, but typically sufficient: preserve all public API:

```
-keep public class 3rd_party_lib_name.** {
    public *;
}
```

Even less conservative: only preserve public classes, but not necessarily their fields or methods:

```
-keep public class 3rd_party_lib_name.**
```

Some experimentation can go along way.

As ben75 mentions, this doesn't account for third party libraries performing reflection on your own code.

Comment: This looks good. My problem is mainly that no matter which approach I take, I can't immediately tell if it broke my application - bugs could appear months later in some module and I'd never be able to tell that it was caused by this. This is the main thing that worries me.

Answer (score 0):

Since some libraries use reflection or json conversion for some classes, if you do not keep library classes, your app will not work properly. For a sample case,
I used honeywell rfid library with proguard. When some classes and enums are not kept, a strange case occurred. When trying to write an rfid tag, even if it has failed, library was returning that it was a successfull writing. All other methods was working properly. So what to do for protecting your own code.
Open the third party library file by double clicking it in Android Studio. Enter into the classes.jar file and determine which packages are used. Then keep these packages in the proguard file.

As an example :
[![third party packages to include][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr2fb.png

proguard-rules.pro file must look like this.

```
-keep class com.honeywell.** { *; }
-keep class com.silionmodule.** { *; }
-keep class com.bth.** { *; }
-keep class com.communication.** { *; }
-keep class com.thingmagic.** { *; }
-keep class com.tool.** { *; }

-keep enum com.honeywell.** { *; }
-keep enum com.silionmodule.** { *; }
-keep enum com.bth.** { *; }
-keep enum com.communication.** { *; }
-keep enum com.thingmagic.** { *; }
-keep enum com.tool.** { *; }
```