# Multiple warnings when building using Proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I really want to use this `Proguard` feature with my app but seeing those thousand warnings makes me wonder if it is worthy... What should I add to make it build successfully? Or let me know if it's a lost causes...

Here is my `Gradle` file:

(...)

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable 'LongLogTag'
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 21
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.4.0'
    compile("com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile("com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'jackson-databind'
    }
    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile('com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    // This one use Maven : url "https://jitpack.io"
    compile('org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    }
    compile('com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.9') {
        exclude group: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'info.guardianproject.iocipher:IOCipher:0.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    compile ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0"){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0"){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.+'
    compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.securesharedpreferences:securesharedpreferences:1.0.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3@aar'
    compile 'com.bigkoo:pickerview:2.0.8'
    compile 'com.takwolf.android:lock9view:0.0.11'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.hanks.animatecheckbox:library:0.1'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.5'
}

apply plugin: ('com.google.gms.google-services')
```

Here is my proguard-rule.pro file:

```
##########################
#        RETROFIT        #
##########################

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes Annotation

##########################
#       BUTTERKNIFE      #
##########################

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

##########################
#     JACKSON-PARSER     #
##########################
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** e(...);
public static *** wtf(...);
    }
```

and those are the remaining warnings:

```
(…)
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.deser.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.activation.DataSource
Warning:javax.ws.rs.core.Link$JaxbAdapter: can't find superclass or interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.Activator: can't find superclass or interface org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoaderImpl$BundleTracker: can't find superclass or interface org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry: can't find superclass or interface org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider$ByteArrayDataSource: can't find superclass or interface javax.activation.DataSource
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.AdapterConverter: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector$1: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.deser.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer: can't find referenced class javax.activation.DataHandler
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.deser.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer$1: can't find referenced class javax.activation.DataSource
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.ser.DataHandlerJsonSerializer: can't find referenced class javax.activation.DataHandler
Warning:com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AnimatorProxy: can't find referenced method 'float floor(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AnimatorProxy: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:javassist.tools.rmi.ObjectImporter: can't find referenced class java.applet.Applet
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector$Argument
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachineManager
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine
Warning:javax.ws.rs.core.Link$JaxbAdapter: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
Warning:javax.ws.rs.core.Link$JaxbLink: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute
Warning:javax.ws.rs.core.Link$JaxbLink: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Converter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Joiner$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.MoreObjects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.MoreObjects$ToStringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$3: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Predicates$ObjectPredicate$4: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Predicates$OrPredicate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.Activator: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.Activator: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleReference
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ResourceFinderImpl: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.BeanReflectionHelper: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleReference
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry$2: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry$BundleSpiProvidersLoader: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.ConcurrentHashMapV8: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.ConcurrentHashMapV8$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.ConcurrentHashMapV8$TreeBin: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.LinkedTransferQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.LinkedTransferQueue$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.LinkedTransferQueue$Node: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.SecurityEntityFilteringFeature: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Invocable
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ServerScopeProvider: can't find referenced class org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.FilteringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider: can't find referenced class javax.activation.DataSource
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider$ByteArrayDataSource: can't find referenced class javax.activation.DataSource
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.RenderedImage
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.RenderedImage
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageWriter
Warning:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.RenderedImage
(…)
Note: there were 4 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 11 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 143 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 30 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Warning:there were 1911 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProdRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProdRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7.152 secs
Information:1 error
Information:901 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I typically need to tell proguard to keep third party libraries for it to build successfully. For example, Id add the following for Okio and fasterxml:

```
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
```

Add the above for each third party library you've included in your project. From your logs I see glassfish, jersey, squareup, google, Okio, and fasterxml.

Here is some more information on the above listed proguard rules:

[Using "dontwarn" in proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693914/using-dontwarn-in-proguard)

[Android Proguard - is it best practice to -keep all 3rd party libs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644854/android-proguard-is-it-best-practice-to-keep-all-3rd-party-libs)